# Get `is not recognized as an internal or external command` from dependency's package.json on Windows10

Tags: npm, node-modules

In a legacy project I have to set up, on Windows 10, the first thing we have to do is `yarn install` - but then then I get:

```
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\...\project\node_modules\dependency-ui: Command failed.
Exit code: 255
Command: NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR=${NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR:-}; $NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR/.bin/yarn-postinstall | true
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\...\project\node_modules\dependency-ui
Output:
'NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

And when I open the package.json file of that `dependency-ui` - I see:

```
...

  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR=${NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR:-}; $NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR/.bin/yarn-postinstall | true",
    ...
```

I tried to set this `NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR` - and now I have it as an environment variable - but still get the same error.

Could it be that the syntax in this `postinstall` script is wrong? Or incompatible with Windows?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day - I installed `cross-env` globally and when I append it to the `postinstall` script in the dependency package.json - then it works.

(There was this annoyance that if I run `yarn install` - it overrides the dependency's package.json file and the change with `cross-env` goes away and I get the same error. Thus - after this fails - I do the change with the `cross-env` and then run `yarn postinstall` - which de facto does the trick :) ...)